# Why the controllability matrix $C$ of a matrix $A$ has full rank but the controllability Gramian matrix is singular and notinvertible?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, positive-definite, optimal-control, linear-control

I have an implementation which is working on a matrix $A$. Actually I am checking it's Gramian matrix. If my understanding is correct, a linear time invariant system with adjacency matrix $A$, $\dot x(t) = Ax(t) + Bu$ is controllable if the controllability matrix

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} B & AB & A^2B & \dots & A^{n-1}B\end{bmatrix}$$

has full row rank. Then we have the controllability Gramian

$$\textit{W} = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} e^{At}BB^Te^{A^Tt} \, \mathrm d t$$

If the systme is controllable, the controllability Gramian matrix is positive definite. If controllability matrix $C$ does not satisfy the full row rank requirement the system is not controllable and the controllability Gramian $W$ is singular and not invertible.

But, I have a matirx $A$ which it's controllability matrix $C$ has full rank and shows that system is controllable but the Gramian matrix $W$ is singular and not invertible. What does it mean ? and what condition makes this state?

For example. suppose the adjacency matrix $A$ is:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
0& 0& 1 \\ 
1& 0& 1 \\
1& 1& 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the input matrix $B$ is:
$$B= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 
0 \\
0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
So the controllability matrix $C$:
$$C= \begin{bmatrix} 
1& 0& 1 \\ 
0& 1& 1 \\
0& 1& 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
has full rank, but the Gramian matrix is singular.
$$W= \begin{bmatrix} 
1.56& 1.09& 1.09 \\ 
1.09& 0.93& 0.93 \\
1.09& 0.93& 0.93 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What are the associated matrices? Because could it be that the $C$ is actually not full rank but due to numerical rounding only appears to be full rank, or the Gramian only appears to be not positive definite due to numerical rounding?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, I have checked the controllability by other ways, like maximum matching. If you run maximum matching on the bipartite graph corresponding to the graph, the unmatched nodes are drivers to create matrix $B$. In this way there is not numerical rounding. So I am sure that the system is controllable.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible. Maybe you can share the actual values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @obareey could you clarify your comment please

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I have edited the post by associated matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have miscalculated the controllability matrix.  We find that
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&1&1}.
$$
The second and third rows are identical, so we see that $C$ fails to have full row rank.  So, the system is not controllable, and it makes sense that the controllability Gramian that you attained was singular.

---

An explanation of why $C$ the system is not controllable in this case: note that the column-vector $B$ is a linear combination of the eignvectors of $A$ associated with eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, namely
$$
v_{\pm} = \left(\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}, 1,1 \right).
$$
We see that $(1,0,0) = \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}(v_+ - v_-)$.

Comment: The adjacency matrix that you have provided is not symmetric, which is a bit strange.  That said, we get the same answer in the end (the upper-right entry of $C$ changes to a $2$).

Comment: I mean that we get the same answer if we replace $A$ with
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0}.
$$

Comment: Your controllability gramian (I assume you took $t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1$) seems to be correct

Comment: oooppsss!! I had a mistake in my implementation of $C$.

Comment: the matrix $A$ in my problem is not symmetric because my network is directed.

Comment: great! the second part of your answer about the reason that why my system is not controllable is really useful for me and I think it gives me a good point of view to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for justifying my Gramian matrix.I need to be sure that it is correct. yes it is between $t_0=0$ and $t_f=1$

Comment: you know, it is more strange for me that why the symmetric matrix that you have provided and my asymmetric matrix which is close to your matrix, are not controllable with one signal. I suppose that a chain (undirected) is controllable with one signal applying to the root, or a chain (directed) is controllable with one signal applying to the source !!!

Comment: @samie actually the situation with the symmetric matrix is fundamentally different.  Because the symmetric has a repeated eigenvalue (and a non-defective associated eigenspace), there is **no choice** of column-vector $B$ that will result in a controllable system.  That is, we will always need at least two signals

Comment: @samie it seems that no matter which value we choose for the second entry of the first column, we get an uncontrollable system (and the last two rows of $C$ are the same); I wonder if there's a neat, general explanation for that.  In particular, we find that
$$
A  = \pmatrix{0&t&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0} \implies C = \pmatrix{1&0&t+1\\0&1&1\\0&1&1}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it is not just the first entry of the second column, namely the following system matrix is also always uncontrollable with the given $B$: $$ A  = \pmatrix{0&w&x\\1&y&1-y\\1&1-z&z}$$

Comment: @samie I found an explanation: for all of these matrices $A$, $A^T$ has $(0,-1,1)$ as an eigenvector, which means that $(0,-1,1)^\perp$ is an invariant subspace of $A$.  Hence, the vector $B = (1,0,0)$ is taken from a proper invariant subspace of $A$, which means that the resulting controllability matrix does not have full rank.

Comment: @Kwin Interesting observation; thanks for that.  See the comment above this one as well.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen how did you find all possible matrix $A$ which is not controllable by 
 given matrix $B$ ? could you explain please.

Comment: @samie That's not all possible matrices $A$.  For instance, we can add any multiple of the identity to $A$ and maintain this property

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I got your nice explanation but could you clarify for me that why if the $B$ is taken from a proper invariant subspace of $A$, then the controllability matrix does not have full rank ? be sure that your comments from first are really useful for me to understand my problem.

Comment: @samie the column-span of the controllability matrix is equal to the smallest $A$-invariant subspace that contains every column of $B$.  So, if $B$ is a single vector taken from an $A$-invariant subspace $U \subsetneq \Bbb R^n$, then the column space of the controllability matrix is a subspace of $U$.  For the controllability matrix to have full rank, its column space needs to be all of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, these days I have worked on it to apply in my implementation. I dont want to calculate controllability matrix and check it's rank. So I have tried to apply your explanation about the eigenvectors of $A^T$ and matrix $B$ which maybe is taken from a proper invariant subspace of $A$. But you know, while this explanation is nice but its not possible to implement and check it. do you have any idea ? does it have any affect on any parameter or is reachable by checking any thing else ? Thank you

Comment: @samie Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.  I understand that your implementation requires that we determine whether a given pair $A,B$ is controllable (i.e. describes a controllable system).  Of course, this question was geared towards the particular matrix you asked about; if we want a method that works in general, then the best approach is either to consider the controllability matrix or apply the [Hautus test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma).  If you want something that works better, we would have to take advantage of the structure of $A$ and $B$ somehow.

Comment: @samie If all we know is that $A$ is an adjacency matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, then I don't think we can come up with anything more efficient

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes I am trying to take advantage of the structure of $A$ and $B$ to predict the controllability of the pair $(A,B)$ or also approximate it that I think there is not any way except controllability matrix or Hautus test that you said or Gramian matrix. But I will try more. thank you. You have guided me very well